# How can I get my movie clip to resize according to screen size?

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash

I have a movie clip (startMenu); inside it there are buttons, text, and graphics. This is a game I am making, and it will be played on different screen sizes of Android. This is the code I have so far:

```
stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT
startMenu.addEventListener(Event.RESIZE, resizeLayout);
function resizeLayout(e:Event):void
{
    setPosition();
}
function setPosition():void
{
     startMenu.x = (stage.stageWidth - startMenu.width) / 2;
        startMenu.y = (stage.stageHeight - startMenu.height) /2;
}
```

When I run it on different phones using debugging, it locks on the left hand corner, but does stretch out to fit the whole screen. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

If your content stretches when you resize it and your `stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;` you're probably modifying the width/height of the clip somewhere.

As I cannot see your code base I could only imagine it would look something like this:

```
// deforms the image
myClip.width = stage.fullScreenWidth;
myClip.height = stage.fullScreenHeight;
```

instead you should resize only one dimension and adjust the other percentage based, like this:

```
// keeps ratio
myClip.width = stage.fullScreenWidth;
myClip.scaleY = myClip.scaleX;
```

Surely, you can't always know by which side to scale the content, so you might want to check what side is larger first. For example like this:

```
if (myClip.width > myClip.height)
{
    myClip.width = stage.fullScreenWidth;
    myClip.scaleY = myClip.scaleX;
}
else
{
    myClip.height = stage.fullScreenHeight;
    myClip.scaleX = myClip.scaleY;
}
```

and then, like you did, align the clip to the container:

```
// multiplication works faster, keep that in mind if resizing on each frame or something like this
// But more importantly - getting width/height is pretty expensive, for frequent resizing pre-calculate and store the width height to avoid recalculation
startMenu.x = (stage.stageWidth - startMenu.width) * .5;
startMenu.y = (stage.stageHeight - startMenu.height) * .5;
```